# How to display json object stored in MySQL with AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

In my MySQL database I have column with json string like this:

```
[{id:1,name:"VEZAN ZA PROJEKT 1"}, {id:1, name:'VEZAN ZA PROJEKAT 2'}]
```

I am trying to display values inside template like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, val) in singletask.depencies">
    {{val}}
</span>
```

But get error:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys. Repeater: (key, val) in singletask.depencies,
>   Duplicate key: string::, Duplicate value: :

If I add `track by $index` it will display full json sting separated with spaces...

Anyone know what is problem?

**EDIT**

I pull JSON from array of object. Here is how my objects look like:

```
{
    tasks : [
        0 : Object
        1 : Object
    ],
    admin_id : 1,
    created_at : "2015-11-02 16:16:27",
    depencies : "[{id:1,name:" VEZAN ZA PROJEKT 1 "}, {id:1, name:'VEZAN ZA PROJEKAT 2'}]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is coming back as a string from the DB, not as a JavaScript object. To convert it you can use something like https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

If you still have problems, post more of your code.

Edit:
In your controller, after you have received your data, you need to run a foreach loop on your collection of tasks (or if you only have one task, just do it once) to change the string object into a JavaScript object.

```
$http.get("/api/data").then(function(result){
    $scope.singletask = result.data

    angular.forEach($scope.singletask, function(value, key) {
        value.dependencies = angular.fromJson(value.dependencies);
    }
}
```

Then, when you go to the `ng-repeat="(key, val) in singletask.dependencies"` it will iterate over the array object.

Comment: I also tought about that.... But problem is my json is inside object... So I need inside template to convert that json string...

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you're getting a JavaScript object back, but it's something like {'data': [{id:1,name:"VEZAN ZA PROJEKT 1"}, {id:1, name:'VEZAN ZA PROJEKAT 2'}]}?   If you can, please post some more info about what you're getting, and what you are expecting.

Comment: I updated main post.... I get array of object and I in agngular template take them with for each... But also I need make one more foreach inside that for each to take all `depencies` and depencies is json string... I expect to display every depency name,,,

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: foreach will slow code execution is there any filter to do that directly in template?

Comment: No matter what, if this is done on the client side, you have to iterate over the collection and parse the data. Doing so as a filter is bad, as they are evaluated every digest cycle. It is most logical and performant to parse the data once upon reception, rather than using a filter in-template that is evaluated on each digest.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent infinite digest cycle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94003/discussion-between-ron-brogan-and-vladimir-djukic).